# Can you be tracked while using a vpn?

Tags: malware, tracking

Can you be tracked even with a vpn? If a sophisticated eithical hacker really wanted you will a vpn save you?

Comment: Have you considered that the VPN service you are using could be tracking you? You are routing all your data through their service. Even if your VPN claims to be "logless", there is no way for you to verify whether that is the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How well can Tor + VPN secure my anonymity on the internet?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212129/how-well-can-tor-vpn-secure-my-anonymity-on-the-internet), [Can you still be tracked when using a VPN?](/questions/73816/), [How to configure VPN to get maximum anonymity from my ISP?](/questions/265339/), [Can the government monitor my online activity when I use VPN?](/questions/106098/).